# Redirect Webpage every friday at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function today(hour, minute) {
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(hour);
now.setMinutes(minute);
now.setSeconds(0);
now.setMilliseconds(0);
return now.getTime();
}

var now = new Date();
now = now.getTime();

if(
(now > today(11, 45) && now < today(14, 00)) ||
(now > friday(19, 00) && now < saturday(0, 00))
) {
alert("Lunchtime Specials!");
window.location = "http://google.ie";
}</script>
```

it works for the "today" but but not friday or saturday etc
any advice?

Comment: can you post the `friday` and `saturday` functions?

Comment: Hey, your Friday 19-23:59 may be some one else Friday noon or saturday. So, you should be basing your timing on UTC time zone. Also, if the user has changed the time in the local machine, then the javascript will fail. I recommend to do the redirection in server side.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to check what day it is, then what time, to get day of the week Friday:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();

if(day == 5){
alert("It's Friday!");
}
```

> **getDay()** returns the day of the week (from 0-sunday to 6-sat)

If you want to check an hour, or minute, do the following (following from top code):

```
var hour = d.getHours();

if(hour == 11){
alert("It's 11 AM! Woo");
}
```

For full documentation on the **date object** look here:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

Comment: I want to redirect users every friday between 19.00 and 0.00,

Comment: @DanielMoore, ok? and.. did I not give you the tools to do it? Simply in place of the `alert` add your redirect..